# How to show google video snippet in SERP without paid search?

Tags: video, google-search

I have follow same structure as http://www.dailymotion.com/

while dailymotion display it but not my site. any reason?
video thumbnail is not display on SERP . mysite is http://www.easywebvideo.com/

i have submit sitemap to google.site map is http://www.easywebvideo.com/video_sitemap/files/sitemap_1.xml

i have follow same structure as http://www.dailymotion.com/
while dailymotion display it but not my site. any reason?

try to seacrh "Door knob Hanger Printing Boone North Carolina" in google.